# MySQL - Using subqueries on join and from

Tags: mysql, subquery

I am trying to return the CustomerID, CompanyName, OrderID, and subtotals for each customer for all order the subtotal amounts that are higher than the customer’s average subtotal amount. These are the tables I am using and the query below. I am unsure if the values I return are correct and was hoping someone could help me understand if they are or not based on my query. Thanks in advance.

```
Orders
 Columns
  OrderID
  CustomerID
  EmployeeID
  OrderDate
  RequiredDate

OrderDetails
 Columns
  OrderID
  ProductID
  UnitPrice
  Quantity

Products
 Columns
  ProductID
  ProductName
  QuantityPerUnit
  UnitPrice

Customers
 Columns
  CustomerID
  CompanyName
  ContactName
  Country





SELECT A.CustomerID, A.CompanyName, A.Subtotal, A.OrderID, AVGSubtotal
FROM (
    SELECT
        C.CustomerID,
        C.CompanyName,
        (D.UnitPrice * P.QuantityPerUnit) AS Subtotal,
        D.OrderID
    FROM Customers C
        JOIN Orders O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
        JOIN OrderDetails D ON D.OrderID = O.OrderID
        JOIN Products P ON P.ProductID = D.ProductID
    GROUP BY
        D.OrderID, C.CustomerID
) A
JOIN (
    SELECT
        S.CustomerID, S.CompanyName, AVG(S.Subtotal) as AVGSubtotal
    FROM (
        SELECT
            C.CustomerID,
            C.CompanyName,
            (D.UnitPrice * P.QuantityPerUnit) AS Subtotal
        FROM Customers C
            JOIN Orders O ON C.CustomerID = O.CustomerID
            JOIN OrderDetails D ON D.OrderID = O.OrderID
            JOIN Products P ON P.ProductID = D.ProductID
        GROUP BY
            D.OrderID, C.CustomerID
        ) S
    GROUP BY
        S.CustomerID
) B ON A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID 
WHERE
    A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID AND 
    A.Subtotal > B.AVGSubtotal 
ORDER BY
    A.CustomerID, A.CompanyName
;
```

Comment: Are you wanting some to "Review your Code"?  If there are no errors/failures, then Q&A is not the place for your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
  c2.customerID,
  c2.CompanyName,
  c2.AVGSubtotal
  o2.OrderID,
  o2.UnitPrice * o2.Quantity as subtotal
from (
  select
    c.CustomerID,
    c.CompanyName,
    sum(o.UnitPrice * o.Quantity)/count(*) as AVGSubtotal
  from
    Customers c
    inner join Orders o on (o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID)
    inner join OrderDetails od on (od.OrderID = c.OrderID)
  group by
    o.CustomerID  
) as c2
inner join Orders o2 on (o2.CustomerID = c2.CustomerID)
where o2.UnitPrice * o2.Quantity > c2.AVGSubtotal
```